# Can JSP and Python used together for same database?

Tags: java, android, python, database, jsp

I'm a student who work part-time at a start-up, which runs a website made with JSP.

We are planning an android app in this summer and I'm considering developing it with Python, which I'm interested in.

However, the service provided by the app is supposed to be added to the website made with JSP later.  I'm afraid the difference of the language would cause any obstacle.

Since they will use a common database, I think using different languages to access it won't have any problem.  I want to make sure that my guess is correct.

Pardon my poor English.  I'd appreciate your answers.

Comment: First off, **NO**, don't develop and Android app in python. There is no workable tool chain available. Secondly, a database cares very little what language you use to access it. You'd use a web-service anyway, in which case the Android app won't even care how the database is implemented.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote this question. It is supposed that OP comes here with a question because he/she doesn't know the answer seeking for help, but instead finds hostility =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend building the API services in the current language used by your start-up. If resources are limited, the company may not wish to maintain services in another language.

Though I would not recommend this, it is definitely possible for you to develop the portions of your Android application in Python and use a different language for the API services (assuming you are willing to use Python libraries like Kivy).

This will allow you to code a chunk of your application logic in Python.

To consider:

http://kivy.org/#home

https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Answer (score 0):

> We are planning an android app in this summer and I'm considering
>   developing it with Python

Native Android apps are developed using Java.

> However, the service provided by the app is supposed to be added to
>   the website made with JSP later. I'm afraid the difference of the
>   language would cause any obstacle.

You will need to create an API that communicates between Android and your database.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered with the answer that helped you the most.